Integral preimages of topologically noetherian, affine schemes
Let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, $d\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and let $C=\bigotimes^d_A B$ the $d$-fold tensor product of $B$ over $A$. Then $\mathfrak{S}_d$, the symmetric group of $d$ elements, acts on $C$ by permuting the entries of the elementary tensors of $C$. We can now consider the surjective, integral map $f\colon\operatorname{Spec}(C)\to \operatorname{Spec}(C^{\mathfrak S_d})=\operatorname{Spec}(C)/\mathfrak S_d$.  Further, note that $f$ is submersive, has finite fibers (as $\mathfrak S_d$ acts transitively on the fibers of $f$) and for $x\in X$ with $y=f(x)$, the fiber is given by $f^{-1}(y)=\bigcup_{g\in \mathfrak S_d}g\cdot x$.
The question I am trying to answer is: If $\operatorname{Spec}(C^{\mathfrak S_d})$ is topologically noetherian, does it automatically follow that $\operatorname{Spec}(C)$ also has to be topologically noetherian?
I have tried to prove the above statement as follows: Let $U\subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(C)$  be an open subset. Then, because $f$ is open, $f(U)$ is quasi-compact and therefore, $f^{-1}(f(U))=\bigcup_{g\in \mathfrak S_d}g\cdot U$ is also quasi compact because $f$ is. So, given any open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $U$, we obtain an open cover $(g\cdot U_i)_{(g,i)\in \mathfrak S_d\times I}$ of $f^{-1}(f(U))$ which is quasi compact. Therefore, we can take a finite subcover $(g\cdot U_1,\dots, g\cdot U_n)_{g\in \mathfrak S_d}$. From this, I would like to deduce that $U_1,\dots, U_n$ cover $U$ already but this does not seem to work. I tried to do this inductively by removing elements of $\mathfrak S_d$ but I cannot get this to work, even when only removing one element. I have also tried to look into counter-examples but was not able to find anything that works.
Any proofs, hints or counter-examples are greatly appreciated.

Lemma: Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map of sober topological spaces which is closed, has finite fibres, and has the following property: for all $y \in Y$ the group $\text{Aut}(X/Y)$ acts transitively on the fibre $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. If $Y$ is Noetherian, then $X$ is Noetherian.
Remark: The lemma is false without the assumption on automorphisms.
Proof. We will use that if $Y' \subset Y$ is closed, then the assumptions made on $f$ hold for the restriction $f|_{f^{-1}(Y')} : f^{-1}(Y') \to Y'$ too. Thus by Noetherian induction, we may assume that for every proper closed subspace $Y'$ of $Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(Y')$ is Noetherian.
If $Y$ is not irreducible, then we can write $Y = Y_1 \cup Y_2$ with $Y_i$ a proper closed subset of $Y$ and we see that $X = f^{-1}(Y_1) \cup f^{-1}(Y_2)$ is a union of two Noetherian subsets, whence $X$ is Noetherian.
Assume $Y$ is irreducible. Let $\xi \in Y$ be its generic point and let $f^{-1}(\xi) = \{\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_r\}$. Denote $X_j$ the closure of $\{\eta_j\}$ in $X$. Then $X_1, \ldots, X_r \subset X$ are the irreducible components of $X$ which map onto $Y$. If $r = 0$, then $f$ is not surjective and $X = f^{-1}(f(X))$ is Noetherian. Thus we may and do assume $r \geq 1$. For $g \in \text{Aut}(X/Y)$ we see that $g(X_1) = X_j$ for some $j$. We conclude that $X = X_1 \cup \ldots \cup X_r$ by the assumption in the lemma.
Let $X \supset Z_1 \supset Z_2 \supset Z_3 \supset \ldots$ be a decreasing sequence of closed subsets. We will show that this sequence stabilizes, which finishes the proof. Looking at the decreasing sequence $Z_i \cap \{\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_r\}$, after renumbering we see that there exists an $0 \leq s \leq r$ and $n$ for all $i \geq n$ we have: $Z_i \supset X_1 \cup \ldots X_s$ and $X_j \not \subset Z_i$ for $r  \geq j > s$. For $i \geq n$ set
$$
T_i = \text{closure of  }Z_i \setminus X_1 \cup \ldots \cup X_s
$$
Note that $Z_i = X_1 \cup \ldots \cup X_s \cup T_i$ and that $f^{-1}(f(T_n)) \supset T_n \supset T_{n + 1} \supset T_{n + 2} \supset \ldots $. If we can show that $f(T_n)$ is a proper closed subset of $Y$, then the sequence of $T_i$ stabilizes, and so does our original sequence, and the proof is complete. To see this note that $T_n \subset X_{s + 1} \cup \ldots \cup X_r$ because $X = X_1 \cup \ldots \cup X_n$. Hence $\eta_j \not \in T_n$ for $j = 1, \ldots, s$. On the other hand, for $j = s + 1, \ldots, r$ the intersection $Z_n \cap X_j$ is a closed subset not containing $\eta_j$. Since clearly $T_n \cap X_j \subset Z_n \cap X_j$ we conclude that $\eta_j \not \in T_n$ for $j = s + 1, \ldots, r$. Thus $\xi \not \in f(T_n)$ as desired. QED

First of all, sorry for the late answer; I expected to receive a notification of some kind in case of an answer but never got one. This answer is exactly what I was trying to prove but did not manage to. Thank you very much!
